# moment utc start from day incorrect

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to get moment to give me the minutes ago since that specific date. I send in date as a UTC time format. The first format to DD MMM YYYY, h:mm a is correct. However, the time ago is all 35 which is incorrect.

```
Sat Nov 11 2017 00:13:45 GMT+0700 (+07)
11 Nov 2017, 12:13 am
35 minutes ago
Sat Nov 11 2017 00:10:46 GMT+0700 (+07)
11 Nov 2017, 12:10 am 
35 minutes ago
Sat Nov 11 2017 00:12:08 GMT+0700 (+07)
11 Nov 2017, 12:10 am 
35 minutes ago
Sat Nov 11 2017 00:07:57 GMT+0700 (+07)
11 Nov 2017, 12:07 am
35 minutes ago
```

Code:

```
    console.log(date)
    console.log(moment(date).local().format('DD MMM YYYY, h:mm a'))
    if(today.diff(date, 'days') < 5){
        date = moment(date).local().startOf('day').fromNow()
        console.log(date)            
    }else{
        date = moment(date).local().format('DD MMM YYYY, h:mm a')
    }
```

Comment: Note `.local()` is extraneous here.  It doesn't do anything when the moment is already in local mode.  `moment(...)` creates a moment in local mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use diff instead, and then specify the units as minutes.

```
let date = '2017/02/22 08:42:22';
let diff = moment(date).diff(moment(date).startOf('day'), 'minutes');
```

You can also do

```
let date = '2017/02/22 08:42:22';
let diff = moment(date).diff(moment(date).startOf('day'));
```

Which returns the difference as milliseconds and then display it via

```
moment.duration(diff).asMinutes();
moment.duration(diff).asHours();
```

etc.

If you want to mix units you can do:

```
`${Math.floor(moment.duration(diff).asHours())}:${moment.duration(diff).minutes()}`
```

[Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

edit: oops, forgot proper syntax. Thats what I get for writing this from memory

Comment: This is great.How can I get it to fit in with my code? What I want is for it to do something like, 30 minutes ago, then 3 hours ago, then 4 days ago and anything past 4 days will go into the else statement which works fine.

Comment: `if(date1.diff(date2, 'minutes') > 30)` / `if(date1.diff(date2, 'hours') > 3)` / `if(date1.diff(date2 'days') > 4)`

Comment: when you structure those conditionals I would check the largest time difference first, then the second largest etc. If you check the smallest first then it you will have cases where something happened 3 hours ago and 30 minutes ago but it will be true for both. @ThomasCharlesworth

Comment: moment(date).diff(moment(date).startOf('day'), 'minutes') returns 13 minutes which is wrong. date = Sat Nov 11 2017 00:13:45 GMT+0700 (+07) but right now it is Sat Nov 11 2017 01:02:23 GMT+0700 (+07) it should be like 49 minutes

Comment: it's not incorrect, that is the difference in minutes. If you don't specify the unit, the wrap the diff variable in a duration object `diff = moment.duration(diff)` then specify `diff.asHours()` you will get the total amount of hours passed, if you say `diff.hours()` you will get the hours value , not accounting for minutes, seconds etc

Comment: I'm re running this every five minutes and its always returning 13 minutes.

Comment: @ThomasCharlesworth check out this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/7kqpd2hf/1/ notice that `diff.asMinutes()` is 733.75 minutes but `diff.minutes()` is 13

Comment: Maybe I'm just using this whole thing wrong but all I want is for it to say how many minutes has passed since the date given. If into the hours, how many hours since that date then how many days since that date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158723/discussion-between-robbie-milejczak-and-thomas-charlesworth).